# FFMpeg - Negative Mapping Duplicates Subtitle Tracks

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm attempting to remove a DTS-HD track from an existing media item using a command like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i source.m4v -map 0 -map -0:a:1 -c copy output.m4v
```

Here's the `ffprobe` of the original:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 4365 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 47.95 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13 03:57:02
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13 03:57:02
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32p (24 bit), max. 200 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13 03:57:02
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13 03:57:02
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

and the ffprobe of the result of the `ffmpeg` command run above:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 4365 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 47.95 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574) (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

As you can see the subtitle track has been duplicated, and set to show by default. Can anyone clarify how I would remove just the DTS-HD track and leave everything else remaining please?

`ffmpeg` version info:

```
ffmpeg version N-79277-g0c90b2e Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 20.100 / 55. 20.100
  libavcodec     57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
  libavformat    57. 32.100 / 57. 32.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 41.100 /  6. 41.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

When attempting with a newer version of `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version N-82579-g28d8789 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-g
nutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-lib
mp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-l
ibsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-lib
x264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      55. 40.100 / 55. 40.100
libavcodec     57. 66.106 / 57. 66.106
libavformat    57. 58.100 / 57. 58.100
libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
libavfilter     6. 67.100 /  6. 67.100
libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.10
```

I get the following when running the same command above:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 4365 kb/s, 
23.98 fps, 
47.95 tbr, 
90k tbn, 
180k tbc
 (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13T03:57:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13T03:57:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32p (24 bit)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13T03:57:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Surround
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-13T03:57:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
[ipod @ 000000000302fb20] 
Tag text/0x74786574 incompatible with output codec id '100359' ([0][0][0][0])
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (copy)
   Last message repeated 1 times
```

Here's the Pastebin of the output of the most recent command: http://pastebin.com/K4TErxh8

Comment: Run your original command with `-report`added and paste the textfile generated.

Comment: Also try a [more recent `ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), and if possible please provide a link to a short sample file so we can attempt to duplicate the issue.

Comment: @Mulvya and @LordNeckbeard -- I've updated the version of `ffmpeg` and provided a pastebin of the `ffmpeg` output (I get an error this time).

Comment: I suppose DTS is not supported by the "iPod" muxer (M4V). You can attempt to output to MP4 instead. Can you provide a short input file?

Comment: No I can't really provide a short input file. The stream I'm trying to remove is an DTS-HD stream so I'm a bit confused why that would cause a problem. I tried by adding an option `-dn` to the command and that appeared to work.